# Doctrine 2. query builder. association INSTANCE OF type

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, instanceof

I have the following request on DQL, using Doctrine 2 Query Builder, which works well:

```
$qb->select('post')
    ->from('Posts\Entity\Post','post')
    ->join('post.author','author')
    ->where('author INSTANCE OF :utype')
    ->setParameter('utype',$userType);
```

But, considering that this example reflects a part of large query, I'd like to get rid of this `join`. I tried this:

```
$qb->select('post')
    ->from('Posts\Entity\Post','post')        
    ->where('post.author INSTANCE OF :utype')
    ->setParameter('utype',$userType);
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I avoid using `join`? Or maybe there is other ways to optimize such query?

Thank's

Comment: what error do does occur?

Comment: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_INSTANCE, got '.' near post.author

Comment: posts and author are 2 different tables. the join field in posts will just be an ID. So you will defentely have to make a join.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to access discriminator column? However it involves join as well..

Comment: Any way, I've discovered the reason of performance issue. It's not about join, it's  caused by OR condition in join statement in another part of query:
`$qb->join($userType,'u','WITH','post.destination_member_id=u.id OR post.author_id=u.id');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but the answer is still missing.
The instance name can not be set as string via parameters.

It could be written like this:

```php
$qb->select('post')
    ->from('Posts\Entity\Post','post')        
    ->where('post.author INSTANCE OF '.UserType::class);
```

or like this

```php
$qb->select('post')
    ->from('Posts\Entity\Post','post')        
    ->where('post.author INSTANCE OF :utype')
    ->setParameter('utype', $entityManager->getClassMetadata(UserType::class));
```

@see: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6483